# How can i save a cropped image (Cropped with my cropping tool) on my webserver with a new name that i can give with an input field?

Tags: javascript, php

[image: Like This?]

I made a picture cropping tool. Uploading and cropping the picture works great!

However, I want you to be able to choose the name of the picture that you've cropped yourself using an input field. Unfortunately this does not work...I have already tried to make a PHP Variable to get the value of the input field. But if i click on the Button: Bild absenden It wont save any name...

Here is the whole folder:
https://bbwch-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/nico_birrer_lernende_bbw_ch/EmcVx2jxkSZLvUDSkobXhy8BgIrdzaLOzWOZ9CTCf4gk2A?e=FxdSfd

Here is my code:

index.php:

```
<?php 
include('/header.php');
?>
<title>Badge-Fotos zuschneiden speichern</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="croppie/croppie.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="croppie/croppie.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="upload.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Badge-Fotos zuschneiden & speichern</h2>    
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <div id="upload-image"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <strong>Bild auswählen:</strong>
                <br/>
                <input type="file" id="images">
                <br/>
                <strong>Name:</strong>
                <br/>
                <form method="get" action="upload.php">
                <input type="text"
                       id="Mitarbeiternummer"
                       autocomplete= "off"
                       name="manummer"
                       required
                >
                <br/>
                </form>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-success cropped_image" >Bild absenden</button>
                
            </div>          
            <div class="col-md-4 crop_preview">
                <div id="upload-image-i"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <br>    
</div>
```

upload.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $image_crop = $('#upload-image').croppie({
        enableExif: true,
        viewport: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            type: 'square'
        },
        boundary: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        }
    });
    $('#images').on('change', function () { 
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
                url: e.target.result
            }).then(function(){
                console.log('jQuery bind complete');
            });         
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });
    $('.cropped_image').on('click', function (ev) {
        $image_crop.croppie('result', {
            type: 'canvas',
            size: 'viewport'
        }).then(function (response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://"mywebserver"",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"image":response},
                success: function (data) {
                    html = '<img src="' + response + '" />';
                    $("#upload-image-i").html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
$croped_image = $_POST['image'];
list($type, $croped_image) = explode(';', $croped_image);
list(, $croped_image)      = explode(',', $croped_image);
$croped_image = base64_decode($croped_image);
include 'index.php';
$image_name = 'Hallo';
$image_type = '.jpg';
// upload cropped image to server 
file_put_contents('upload/'.$image_name .$image_type, $croped_image);
echo 'Cropped image uploaded successfully.';
?>
```

Comment: So what did you actually improve now, between this, and your previous question under a different nickname, that got closed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132920/

Comment: I've changed the whole thing.. I've also improved the question etc.

Comment: Really? Code looks pretty much the same as before to me. Okay, so what is the _actual_ problem then (and don’t say “doesn‘t work”)? Right now, you are not sending any name via POST, and your PHP script only seems to try and use the values from $image_name and $image_type. So what about this is not working? Doesn’t create any file at all? Wrong name? Wrong content? And what have _you_ done so far to try and debug this?

Comment: I'm sorry :(       The actual Problem is, when I crop the image and click on Upload Image, the image is saved without any name (right now the name is for example "Hello". $image_name should be the text from the HTML input field afterwards. But I don't know how to create this variable or create it correctly to fill $image_name.

Comment: So the input field named `manummer` should hold that name? Then start by removing the form, that makes little sense there. And then, read the value of that field, and add it to the POST parameters you are sending with your AJAX request. Right now, you are _only_ sending the image data.

Comment: Ok, could you explain that for a beginner? I'm very sorry that's my first PHP/JavaScript project.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? (You know what’s _actually_ meant to explain stuff to beginners? Beginner _tutorials_, not us.)

Comment: No, I mean what I have to change

Comment: I just don't understand what you meant by the previous comment!

Comment: I just don't understand which form to remove.

Comment: The _one_ form there currently is. You are submitting the whole thing via AJAX here, so the form has little purpose - remove it, and keep just the input field for the file name.

Comment: @CBroe could you check the image in the body? Is it correct like this?

Comment: You need to keep the input field for the name.

Comment: Like I did it right now? (picture is in the body)

Comment: Yes. Now you got to read the value from that field, and add it to the POST data you are sending via AJAX.

Comment: @CBroe am I doing this with a PHP variable?

Comment: $_POST['manummer']; is this correct?

Comment: @CBroe I've updated the picture

Comment: You need to add it into the data you send with the AJAX request now.

Comment: Like I did it right now? (picture)

Comment: No. That is not even valid JS syntax now. You really need to go and learn some basics, and go read up on how some of the stuff you intend to use here actually works.